# How i can pass multiple array postion and their items to next activity and to get in next activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, indexing

I am going to develope gym app, in this app i have a list of different workout and each workout has many sets,so now if i click on one workout i want to send workout name and its item position to next activity and want to get both workout name and its item position in next activity. below is my code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    getInt = intent.getStringExtra("Workout");

    switch (getInt)
    {
        case "abs":
           CustomAdaperAbs absAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, absImages, absname,"abs");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(absAdapter);
            break;
        case "back":
            CustomAdaperAbs backAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, backImages, backname, "back");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(backAdapter);
            break;
        case "biceps":
            CustomAdaperAbs bicepsAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, bicepImages, bicepname, "biceps");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(bicepsAdapter);
            break;
        case "calves":
            CustomAdaperAbs calvesAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, calvesImages, calvesname, "calves");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(calvesAdapter);
            break;
        case "cardio":
            CustomAdaperAbs cardioAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, cardioImages, cardioname, "cardio");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(cardioAdapter);
            break;
        case "chest":
            CustomAdaperAbs chestAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, chestImages, chestname, "chest");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(chestAdapter);
            break;
        case "forearms":
            CustomAdaperAbs foreArmsAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, foreArmImages, foreArmname, "forearms");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(foreArmsAdapter);
            break;
        case "legs":
            CustomAdaperAbs legsAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, legsImages, legsname, "legs");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(legsAdapter);
            break;
        case "shoulder":
            CustomAdaperAbs shoulderAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, shoulderImages, shouldername, "shoulder");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(shoulderAdapter);
            break;
        case "tricep":
            CustomAdaperAbs tricepAdapter = new CustomAdaperAbs(AllWorkout.this, tricepImages, tricepname, "tricep");
            recyclerViewAbs.setAdapter(tricepAdapter);
            break;
            default:
                break;

    }
}
```

here i receive "workout" value from previous activity, now i want to pass workout values with their items to next activity and to get in next activity.
how is it possibe to get array name and their items value in next activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store all the different items in second activity, where they are needed.

In the first activity you just declare, which kind of workout you clicked, something like

```
 OnAbsButtonClick()
        {
            String value = "abs";
            Intent newIntent = new Intent();
            newIntent.putExtra("key", value);
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
```

and on you second activity you get this info, and work with it

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        String value = extras.getString("key");

        if(value == "abs")
        {
            getAbsItem();
        }
    }
```

Comment: sir i have follow your answer but problem is :: video not playing and give me ans is  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer$OnCompletionListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: that does not sound like a problem related to my solution to pass data between to activities.